# Oracle sql line amount minus running amount

Tags: sql, oracle

I have requirement as below

Table-1: NET_INVOICES

```
VEND_ID    INV_ID    INV_AMOUNT    
7070       5123       1200    
7070       5124        800    
7070       5125        600
```

Table-2: NET_TRXS

```
CUST_ID     TRX_ID    TRX_AMOUNT    
7070         8356       800    
7070         8357       600    
7070         8358       300
```

RESULT: I needed this as below result

```
VEND_ID     INV_ID   INV_AMOUNT    TRX_ID      INV_TRX_AMOUNT    
7070         5123      1200         8356          800    
7070         5123      1200         8357          400
7070         5124       800         8357          200    
7070         5124       800         8358          300
```

Comment: Great. How can we help you?

Comment: Using Table-1 and Table-2, I need the Result as displayed in RESULT

Comment: Your result makes no sense. please explain the logic

Comment: Hi @KaushikPola, stackoverflow users are not here to code for you. See here -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. If you run into issues after you tried something, we then might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are missing a foreign key in Table-2 which need's to refer to the column of Table-1 (INV_ID). Then you can link your transactions to incoming invoices by the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table-1 t1, Table-2 t2 WHERE t1.INV_ID=t2.INV_ID
```

That will give you the result as you probably want.

Update:
Hi @KaushikPola, stackoverflow users are not here to code for you. See here -> stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. If you run into issues after you tried something, we then might be able to help you. – Liora Haydont 5 mins ago